# Core Data persistent object located on Amazon S3?

Tags: iphone, core-data, amazon-s3

I am curious if my persistent object of Core Data can be stored and retrieved using Amazon S3.

I think it is a perfect combination to put your application on the cloud.

Or Amazon has other services?

Has anyone had any success stories to share?

Edited:

I know that there is no direct support of Core Data for S3, but there is [ASIS3Request](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/S3) available to save and load any object on S3.

My solution: in the app delegate, I will modify the persistentStoreCoordinator to  save on Amazon S3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a terrible idea to me.  The performance would be abysmal since you are taking something that is inherently designed to be a local cache and moving it up into the cloud.

You are far better off having a local cache and then periodically storing a copy of the file up in the cloud.

What is your goal behind storing the data on S3?

Comment: Ohh thank you very much Marcus! You have cleared my doubt. But how do you appoach on an application that needs to store both data files along with a database in the cloud? An example: A real estate company that offers the users the ability to upload both images, videos and information of the client's house?

Comment: Pretty much the same solution.  I would sync the data up into the cloud periodically and treat the copy that is on the phone as a cache.

Comment: Hi Marcus, is it the normal way of doing a social network application on the iphone? I guess it'll be too complicated :-s

Comment: No, a social network application normally hits a REST server and caches data locally where it makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Though there's no direct Core Data support for Amazon S3 as a store type, Core Data allows [Custom Store Types](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdPersistentStores.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002875-SW6). This fact is referenced in the iPhone Core Data docs, so I assume it's available on the iPhone platform.

Comment: I should've been more specific. Yes, you'd create a custom store type that fetches and saves objects to S3 via some mechanism. ASIS3Request and friends does look promising as such a mechanism.